# linking to guava javadoc

Tags: maven, javadoc, guava

What is the correct URL for linking to Guava javadocs from your project's javadoc?
I'm getting errors when I try to use 
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/index.html
with the  option of the javadoc Maven plugin.
Thanks,
ilya

Comment: Maybe you could share these errors?  The link is clearly a valid javadoc site, so this is probably some maven-specific quirk.

Comment: Do you want to have the JavaDocs available in Eclipse? Otherwise i don't understand the hint to the javadoc plugin?

Comment: Try with same URL without 'index.html'

Comment: @Kevin no, plain javadoc would complain as well, Ischin is right

Comment: Sorry, I just felt the question was a little vague about what exactly "linking to" meant; I read it as more or less "<a href>".

Answer (score 2):

As Ischin says, you need to leave off the "index.html" when linking Javadoc. The Javadoc tool doesn't really care about index.html, it just wants to be able to append the package and class name to get a URL for a particular class's Javadoc.

Comment: ... and it wants to find a `package-list` there.